# Displaying <p> elements in block correctly

Tags: css

**Hey guys! I want to ask how i should display p elements in block**

I have code: [jsFiddle](http://goo.gl/aGFnr) and i have no idea why the HTML display it even after child block bottom? it should move near others elements to the left, but it going on to the foot. How to fix it?

Sorry for my bad english, but i hope you understand and can help me.

- Red borders are only for debugging.

Comment: Where are these `<p>` elements you speak of?

Comment: What are you wanting to happen? Are you wanting the `div` to increase in height so it is big enough for all your `p`s?

Comment: is this http://jsfiddle.net/qZnBE/8/ what you want?

Comment: Try to explain what you are trying to do so that we can help you.

Comment: this is what i want to do :) http://www.part.lt/perziura/f4754af3c0c8542ae5e8f15539b96316252.png

Comment: After a bunch of discussion in the comments it's become apparent that you want a columnar layout. This can't easily be done with CSS. You'll need to either 1) re-order your child elements so you can align them in rows with {display: inline-block}, or 2) use scripting to order them for you.

Comment: okey, i get it and i understand and i will change my child elements, thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using columns and inline-block together:

http://jsfiddle.net/qZnBE/13

```
div#content {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47);
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div#content div.layout {
    columns:5px 4;
    -webkit-columns:5px 4;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-columns:5px 4;
    /* Firefox */
    width: 390px;
    height: 190px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
}
div#content div.layout p {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0;
}

<div id="content">
    <div class="layout">
        <p>one</p>
        <p>two</p>
        <p>three</p>
        <p>four</p>
        <p>five</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that IE < 10 doesn't support CSS columns. http://caniuse.com/multicolumn

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking about inline-block?  display block is already what p tags do by default.

Comment: no, i want to display in block which have 200px height and if it can't fill it in 200px then move next elements to the other block, near the first

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I have got your question right, if you are trying to put all  tags in one-line try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qZnBE/11/)

```
  div#content div.layout a{
   display: block;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   float:left;
  }
```

Comment: {display: block} and {float: left} combine to do the same as {display: inline-block}.

Comment: no, i want to display it in block, but if the content can't fit in 200px (height) it should move to other column, near the first column